# IS NOT NULL doesn't work

Tags: sql, sqlite

my application uses this following sql query (sqlite3 database):

```
select * from DocketTbl where DocketTbl.docket IS NOT NULL
```

However, it doesn't work because the result contains records with NULL values. Please look at the images for more details
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show `SELECT docket, docket IS NULL FROM ...`

Comment: I added the fourth image, it returns no records.

Comment: So, those values are not `NULL`, but a `'NULL'` string presumably.

Comment: What's the difference between them? and how can I eliminate string 'NULL'?

Comment: One is the `NULL` another is a string.

Comment: `UPDATE DocketTbl SET docket = NULL WHERE docket = 'NULL'`

Comment: To confirm what @zerkms presumes, you could try `SELECT docket, LENGTH(docket) FROM DocketTbl`. If the *NULL* records show a length of `4`, you know it's a string for sure

Comment: @Phil: I tried your query and 'NULL' has a length of 0 so I think it's a normal null value, not a 'NULL' string. See the 5th picture

Comment: @lenhhoxung was that before or after my `UPDATE` query (if you ran it at all)

Comment: I mocked this up in SQLFiddle and cannot reproduce the problem ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e1c77/2

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: @Phil: I haven't used the UPDATE command

Comment: @Schwern: It's SQLiteManager

Comment: IMO, the NULL values shown in the GUI tool are not NULL. They are empty strings because their lengths are zero. If they were NULL, `LENGTH(docket)` were NULL. NULL and empty string('') are not same in major DBMS except Oracle. Could you show `select * from DocketTbl where DocketTbl.docket = ''`.

Comment: @KuboTakehiro: You're right, the NULL value is a empty string, I tested that. So I guess the tool's implementation is not really correct

Comment: @lenhhoxung Be sure to [report the bug](http://www.sqlabs.com/contact.php)!